# How to share contact via sms on Android 4.4.2?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, stock-android, motorola-moto-g

I'm using Moto G with stock android running 4.4.2. I would like to share contact detail via SMS. I don't want to use 3rd party app for this basic functionality. Was this functionality available with previous versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kitkat has only 3 defaults for this:

1. Bluetooth
2. Email
3. Gmail

Other options can be added with 3rd Party software, e.g. ES File Exploere adds "Share over LAN".

As per  [the Google products page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/Ingpl6tyUTE) this is a know issue.

> I too am annoyed that this issue is happening with the Nexus 5.I can only hope that they will have an update that will resolve this issue.I work in the transportation industry in which I often have to send forward a contact phone number to another driver and at this point is very cumbersome not to be able to quickly Share a recent calls number with another driver.I've been checking the Play Store to see if there is an App dialer that will resolve this issue for me.

From  [this Android Central thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-5/336090-neophyte-nexus-how-do-i-send-contact-via-text.html)  it confirms that this feature is missing and the solution is to copy and paste, or install 3rd party app.

Without installing a 3rd party application, there is nothing you can do for now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So Is there anyway we can report missing feature in 4.4.2?

Comment: Try Google Code pages here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the contact details
2. Touch the vertical dotted lines for drop-down menu
3. Select share
4. Select messaging from the pull down menu
   now the contact details will be in messaging application and ready to send as mms
5. remove the mms by clicking remove button and send

Answer (score 0):

Using Hangouts I can send contact cards but I have to change MMS delivery using drop down menu on left.(Change from highlighted Blue to Grey MMS delivery. Basically changing from Google Voice to Carrier*)

*On Sprint so my Google Voice number and my Carrier number are the same. Doesn't make sense that I have to change delivery method.

Trying to suggest they smooth out this delivery process, as it should be more fluid to perform a simple task.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Contacts via Sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.huboltapps.contactsviasms&hl=en). It is a simple option to solve this problem in version 4.4.2

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned "I don't want to use 3rd party app for this basic functionality".

Answer (score -1):

Hi go to the contact you wish to share and there you can see the option share aand click it and select via message .

Answer (score -1):

From the Log of the calls..select Name -> and select Send number