# I am using motorala g .I have problem sending contacts via SMS how to resolve it

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I am unable to share the contacts via SMS there no such option can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

what is your android version ? ,
check [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64022/how-to-share-contact-via-sms-on-android-4-4-2?rq=1) and search please before send a question.

and also you can use import/export at " Contact " if your android version is support this option.